# TeamCity - MSBuild - SVN - AssemblyVersion - C#

Tags: c#, svn, msbuild, teamcity

I'm currently using MSBuild+Community Task's to change the AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion + more in AssemblyInfo.cs, via TeamCity and it works like a charm :).

*However I would like to commit the modified AssemblyInfo.cs back to the repo.*

**How can I do that?**

I tried with the "**SvnCommit**" task from **Community Tasks**, but on the Agent's the source is not checked out, it appears to be Exported or copied directly from TC instead (there's no .svn folders). 
This is actually very cool I think and good practise, but in this case I would really like to be able to commit the updated AssemblyInfo.cs files (+maybe so autogenerated documentation) back to the repo.

**Anyone found a nice way of doing this?**

Kind Regards

Garrett

Comment: As far as I know TeamCity has an option who is responsible of the checkouting files, have you tried to turn this on for you Agent? http://screencast.com/t/ZDJhMmNhN

Comment: Ahh your right!   It's right there in front of mw. Don't know how I have missed it, must have looked at it so many times I've gone blind and looked for it in all the wrong places :/.
Thanks, all my problems are solved :-D.

Kind regards
Garrett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Restuta's comment :).