# SvnCommit (MSBuild context) misses one file from the ItemGroup

Tags: svn, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using MSBuild with the community tasks under TeamCity.

Just like Garrett in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141171/teamcity-msbuild-svn-assemblyversion-c), I update my AssemblyInfo.cs files, and then commit them.

In the solution at hand, I've got five AssemblyInfo.cs files, but only four get committed using this MSBuild code:

```
<Target Name="VersionCommit" DependsOnTargets="Version">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="**/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs;" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <SvnCommit Message="Updated verions in AssemblyInfo files." 
               Username="cc" 
               Targets="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)">
    </SvnCommit>
</Target>
```

I've verified that the RegEx pattern above works, i.e. finds all five files.

Any ideas why one of the files doesn't get committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing...

The RegEx pattern worked alright, but a bug in another RegEx used for actually updating the files didn't make the missing file dirty as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `svn add` the file first?

As an aside, people often get fooled by TortoiseSVN which gives you those handy little checkboxes -- they think that when they check a box on the Commit screen that they're somehow passing files to `svn commit` -- what they're really doing is telling Tortoise to `svn add` and then `svn commit`.

Comment: All five files are added and found in the SVN Repository Browser.

Comment: Have you tried running msbuild in verbose mode?  I believe the switch is /v:verbose or something like that.  I can't look it up because I'm on my iphone now... :-)

Comment: TeamCity runs the MSBuild file, and I think the log is pretty verbose. Is there a way to make it even more verbose, i.e. tell TeamCity to use the switch you mention?

I can't run the script locally due to that I don't have SVN installed (maybe a good idea to install it...).